# Android Login into app Via local server connection?

Tags: java, android, http, authentication, localhost

I want to build a login function in my app.

the user credential will be store on the local sever (no internet available). 
So when the user try to login, the app will check the credential  in the localsever.

Can you point me in the right direction . thanks

Comment: So you want to test login functionality of your app on localhost?

Comment: yes. my server is running in the local host. I can connect to it via wifi.

Comment: What problem you're facing then??
Just use ip address of your server instead of localhost in url to connect your API and you're good to go

Comment: What problem you're facing then??
Just use ip address of your server instead of localhost in url to connect your API and you're good to go